# How to handle TypeError after switching to Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, testrail

Recently, We migrated our code from python 2.7 to Python3.6. After this Test rail apis are not working. I tried converting to Unicode, b'get_projectxx' but nothing seems working.

```
 self.project_name = self.client.send_get('get_project/%s' % self.project_id)['name']
```

here, I am passing `self.project_id` as 20

I am getting below error all the time :

```
Exception: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' <class 'TypeError'>
```

Any idea how to fix this issue ? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like `send_get` is the method raising the error (it expects a series of bytes it can send as-is, rather than a string which it would have to encode). Use a `bytes` literal instead of a `str` literal:

```
 self.project_name = self.client.send_get(b'get_project/%s' % self.project_id)['name']
                                          ^
```